# For loop keeps iterating over the same character in a string twice

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that will take a string and switch upper case letters to lower case letters and lower case letters to upper case letters.

I've tried making the function, but the problem is how to tell the function to to only run through each character once. The function runs through the string but it after it changes the upper/lower case to upper/lower case, it changes it back to what it was.

```
def uppertolower (string):
    list1 = []
    for p,l in enumerate(string):
        if p == l.upper():
            l = l.lower()
        elif p == l.lower():
            l = l.upper()
        list1.append(l)
    return ''.join(list1)
```

The following was run:

```
uppertolower('AppLe')
```

Acutal result: AppLe

Expected result: aPPlE

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand what is `p`?

Comment: No! He doesn't.

Comment: position of the tuple in the string

Comment: p is index and l is the element at that index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop doesn’t need to use `p` with `enumerate`. `enumerate` will index the values of the iterable so is always a number.

You cannot compare...

```
p == l.upper()  # or l.lower()
```

...successfully as you are comparing a number to a string. I assume by your description you want to check if the letter is upper or lowercase. You should compare it to itself:

```
def uppertolower(string):
    list1 = []
    for l in string:
        if l == l.upper():
            l = l.lower()
        elif l == l.lower():
            l = l.upper()
        list1.append(l)
    return ''.join(list1)
```

As other answers point out, you could save a comparison by changing the `elif l == l.lower():` to simply `else:` as even characters like numbers will not change when `str.upper` is called.

As a side note, the [`str.swapcase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase) method exists for strings to accomplish what your function does.

Also, I recommend that you use slightly more descriptive variable names such as `char` or `letter` instead of the ambiguous `l` (although it is fairly obvious that `l` stands for `letter`, it could be mistaken for a capital `I` or number `1` in some fonts).

Answer (score 2):

`p` stores the index of the current element, that is `l`. So it makes no sense to compare a `string` and `integer` for equality.

Even after fixing that, your code can be shortened significantly by using the `isupper` and `islower` functions.

```
def uppertolower (x):
    list1 = []
    for l in x:
        if l.isupper():
            l = l.lower()
        else:
            l = l.upper()
        list1.append(l)
    return ''.join(list1)
```

Comment: The `elif` is redundent, you can replace it with `else`.

Answer (score 2):

#### You are doing it the wrong way. There is no need to use `enumerate`:

```
def uppertolower (string):
    list1 = []
    for l in string:
        if l == l.upper():
            l = l.lower()
        else:
            l = l.upper()
        list1.append(l)
    return ''.join(list1)
```

#### However, there is a simple way to do this. Use list comprehensions:

```
def uppertolower(string):
    return "".join([l.lower() if l == l.upper() else l.upper() for l in string])
```

#### Or more simply, use `swapcase`:

```
>>> a = "AppLe"
>>> a.swapcase()
'aPPlE'
>>>
```

---

Output:

```
>>> uppertolower("AppLe")
'aPPlE'
>>>
```